# Can only find by id, not by class, with BeautidulSoup4 (Python3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I am new to `BeautifulSoup4` and ran into a problem that seems elementary. I am only able to find by id, but not by class. For example, I am looking at a site which has the following part of html in it:

[image]

Now, the following works:

```
page_soup.findAll('div', {'id': 'page-content'})
```

whereas the following finds nothing:

```
page_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'main-container'})
```

So my question is: are 'class' treated differnetly from 'id' attributes? If so, what is the proper way to search by class name?

Just for completion, though I think it should not matter, I obtained the html by using the [page_source](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) method of the `selenium` package.

**EDIT**: [Here](http://www.spotrac.com/mlb/atlanta-braves/freddie-freeman-7359/) is an example of such a page. If we inspect the upper table, including the player's position, age, etc., then we get the above html snapshot.

Comment: I'm assuming you made a typo in the second line when posting this question? `{'class: 'main-container'}`

Comment: @DMan, yes thank you, fixed it

Comment: Both lines should return at least one tag. Can you include more code and html data?

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam , The problem is that the html string is huge, so I'm not sure how to include it. That's why I took a screenshot of the relevant part

Comment: What you've done looks right. I assume you can't give us the url for the page?

Comment: Thanks @BillBell, I have added a page similar to the one I'm looking at, as an example.

Comment: I tried and I get correct results for both. They bot return one element each

Comment: does your page have iframe elements?  perhaps you are not getting an element because it sits inside of an iframe.

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani, I get only the first one. Which parser are you using? Or what code did you run before the findAll statement to make it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the commands i run and it works great for me

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: import requests

In [3]: res = requests.get("http://www.spotrac.com/mlb/atlanta-braves/freddie-freeman-7359/")

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

In [5]: len(soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'main-container'}))
Out[5]: 1

In [6]:  soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib")

In [7]: len(soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'main-container'}))
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: import sys; sys.version
Out[8]: '3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:45) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)]'
```

As you can see it works for me in both parsers.